# Discrepancy in timezone between timestamps for lastlogon using WMI commands

Tags: windows, timestamp, wmi, wmic

I'm trying to get the user's last logon in some Windows machines using WMI, but for some reason, this information is different for different commands when I think they should be the same.

The first command that I'm using is : `PATH Win32_NetworkLoginProfile WHERE "Name='DOMAIN\\fakeuser'" GET LastLogon`. The result for it is like below:

> LastLogon
>
> 20181206093540.000000-480

The second command is: `PATH Win32_NTLogEvent WHERE "(EventIdentifier =4648 OR EventIdentifier = 4647 OR EventIdentifier = 4634)" GET CategoryString, TimeGenerated, InsertionStrings`

The result is like below (after some processing to find the last entry of category "Logon"  linked to the "fakeuser", since the command returns a lot of information):

> CategoryString
>
> Logon
>
> InsertionStrings
>
> {"S-1-5-21-3457937927-2839227994-823803824-1104","DOMAIN$","DOMAIN","0x3e6","{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}","fakeuser","DOMAIN","{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}","localhost","localhost","0x64c","C:\Windows\System32\svchost.exe","999.999.99.999","0"}
>
> TimeGenerated
>
> 20181206173540.580545-000

For what I understand for these two commands, the `LastLogon` in the first result should be the same of `TimeGenerated` in the second one. Am I misunderstood something?

In my preliminary research, I found a [possible bug in the WMI Timestamps](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/Lync/en-US/c255a36c-9c37-4a92-8049-bb0dd7b0919d/wmi-starttime-property-in-win32logonsession-class-returning-epoch?forum=ITCG), but I don't know if it is the same problem.

Some additional information:

- These commands are executed using a script that make a remote connection using WinRM connection (ports 5985 and 5986) and then executes the commands to get the info, but I also tried to connect in the machine using RDP and execute it in Powershell with `wmic PATH...`. The result is the same.
- I tested it in Windows 10 and also in Windows Server 2012, but the scripted will be used in some other Windows versions.
- To get the Event numbers for the log class, I used this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/auditing/audit-logon)

After first comment, I noticed that the problem is in time zones. Are there any way to set timezone direct in these commands or convert timezones between them?

Comment: Are you asking about the fractional seconds part? Otherwise the time stamps refer to the same time point, encoded as different time zones.

Comment: Actually, I didn't pay attention in the timestamp. Shame on me.
Do you know any way to force both commands to return the same timestamp? Or I need to post-process the output?

Comment: @IInspectable. Change the timezone of the returned times using a script solved the problem. If you want to post your comment as a answer, I'll mark it as correct.